# How to realize revoke by pressing Ctrl+z in java

Tags: java

I try to programming a TextEditor. Now I can realize it by adding a button. And I want to realize  revoke by pressing `Ctrl+Z`. How to deal with it ?
Please give me some suggestions.

now i can realize it by

```
jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyChar() == 0x1a)) {
            if(doManager.canUndo()) {
                doManager.undo();
            }
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Why this can't?

```
jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
            if(doManager.canUndo()) {
                doManager.undo();
            }
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Why this can't?

```
jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) && (e.isControlDown() == true)) {
            if(doManager.canUndo()) {
                doManager.undo();
            }
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
});
```

@Felix Gerber

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Y with all Text Components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532286/how-to-use-ctrlz-and-ctrly-with-all-text-components) or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030836/undo-functionality-in-jtextarea

Comment: have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541597/how-to-gracefully-handle-the-sigkill-signal-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go would be to add an [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) to your user interface.

Oracle has an little tutorial about writing an own [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html).

Here is an little example checking if `CRTL+Z` is pressed apllied to a `JFrame`:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Your code here!");
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody!

now i can realize it by

```
jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyChar() == 0x1a)) {
            if(doManager.canUndo()) {
                doManager.undo();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
});
```

and

```
jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
            if(doManager.canUndo()) {
                doManager.undo();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) && (e.isControlDown() == true)) {
            if(doManager.canUndo()) {
                doManager.undo();
            }
        }
    }
});
```