# Freeplane/Freemind menu color

Tags: mindmap, freemind

Hi I d'like to know if there is a way to change the color of the main menu (File Edit View Insert ...) of Freemind/Freeplane cause it always appears with a light grey color that somehow it hard to notice there is a menu there.

Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMind and Freeplane both have Java Swing GUIs whose visual appearance is ruled by pluggable "look and feel" (LAF) like [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html). Both programs allow the LAF to be changed via configuration (Tools->Preferences). Exchanging the LAF means changing the whole appearance (not only the menu coloring) but try the other LAF if you like them better.

There are many LAFs (see [How to improve look and feel of JAVA swing GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592207/how-to-improve-look-and-feel-of-java-swing-gui)), some are even user configurable. [This Freeplane forum topic](http://www.freeplane.org/forum2012/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=444) covers how to use them with Freeplane.

Comment: Update for Freeplane 1.5: [Customizing Freeplane Look and Feel](https://sourceforge.net/p/freeplane/discussion/758437/thread/0d656c97/)